# How to attach a vue @click event to a font-awesome icon next to input field?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome-4

I tried to add an @click to a font awesome icon. However, whether I add an @click event to span or i tag, it doesn't work at all. I suspect the event is taken by the input field. How can I make the magnifier icon clickable?

```
<div class="control has-icons-right">
    <input  v-model="keyword" @keyup.enter="findName" class="input is-large" type="text" placeholder="Input 1 word, hit Enter"/>
    <!-- or 2 words separated by space -->                      
      <span class="icon is-right" @click="findName">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </span>
</div>
```

Source: [3sName.com](https://3sname.com/)

Comment: The code works - try it as a CodePen on CodeSandbox and you will see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because, you are using **bulma** class `.icon` which having the following css.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Try to override it with

```
pointer-events: all;
```

`pointer-events` css will prevent your element from emitting a click event.

:)

Answer (score 0):

use a `button / anchor 'a'`  instead `span` to wrap the fa-icon, along with `@click` method? Span isn't good practice for click event as well.

Comment: both button and anchor don't work. Tested in my local PC environment

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `@click.prevent="findName"` modifier?